# Color overlay in android NDK

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, android-ndk

I want to implement the Hue/color/saturation color overlays.
I saw the macros:

```
#define ColorBlend_Saturation(T,A,B) ColorBlend_Hls(T,A,B,HueA,LuminationA,SaturationB)
```

I am trying to reproduce it in Adobe Photoshop with colors `#332244` and `#557711` to get the result color - `#431076`. However, after applying these macros I get color - `#320C59` as the result.

**question 1**: how can I reproduce the photoshop algorithms for hue, saturation and color?

**question 2**: how can I adjust the alpha channel? for example, on my colors and optically == 50, this should be in photoshop - #3b195d

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/blog/862/entry-2249668-pixel-blend-mode-algorithms-including-overlay/ - The idea is the same, look the expressions of the algorithms.

Comment: no, I know about these algorithms. I want color/saturation/hue algorithms

Comment: I think that I can to add alpha channel using ((uint8_t)(O * A + (1 - O) * B)), but I don't know how to adjust saturation/hue/color blends

Comment: What about http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html - here is converion of RGB to HSV and reverse. You could work with RGB and then convert them or the opposite, or even to redesign these algorithms in yours with HSV.

Comment: Rolice, I know about it. currently I implemented these blend modes. BUT. How I can to set alpha channel? because adobe-photoshop color is different from  ((uint8_t)(O * A + (1 - O) * B)) blending.

Comment: Ah, you want exactly Photoshop algorithm?

Comment: I want to make it look like photoshop. Photoshop or gimp... because it have a big difference in the result colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**question 1:**

> Photoshop’s hue, saturation, color, and luminosity blend modes are based on a color space  with dimensions that the article HSL and HSV calls hue, chroma, and luma. Note that this space is different from both HSL and HSV, and  only the hue dimension is shared between the three; see that article for details.
>
> The Hue blend mode preserves the luma and chroma of the bottom layer, while adopting the hue of the top layer.
>
> The Saturation blend mode preserves the luma and hue of the bottom layer, while adopting the chroma of the top layer.
>
> The Color blend mode preserves the luma of the bottom layer, while adopting the hue and chroma of the top layer.
>
> from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes

After more than 3 hours of experimenting i succeded to upgrade HSV -> RGB converter to working saturation blender. Other Blending modes should be simmilar.

Here is code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct HSVColor
{
    float H,S,V;
};

struct RGBColor
{
    float R,G,B;
    RGBColor() = default;
    RGBColor(int r,int g, int b):
        R(r/255.0),
        G(g/255.0),
        B(b/255.0)
    {
    }
};

HSVColor RGBToHSV(const RGBColor& RGB)
{
    float Max;
    float Min;
    float Chroma;
    HSVColor HSV;

    Min = min(min(RGB.R, RGB.G), RGB.B);
    Max = max(max(RGB.R, RGB.G), RGB.B);
    Chroma = Max - Min;

    //If Chroma is 0, then S is 0 by definition, and H is undefined but 0 by convention.
    if(Chroma != 0)
    {
        if(RGB.R == Max)
        {
            HSV.H = (RGB.G - RGB.B) / Chroma;

            if(HSV.H < 0.0)
            {
                HSV.H += 6.0;
            }
        }
        else if(RGB.G == Max)
        {
            HSV.H = ((RGB.B - RGB.R) / Chroma) + 2.0;
        }
        else //RGB.B == Max
        {
            HSV.H = ((RGB.R - RGB.G) / Chroma) + 4.0;
        }

        HSV.H *= 60.0;
        HSV.S = Chroma / Max;
    }

    HSV.V = Max;

    return HSV;
}

RGBColor Saturate(const HSVColor& HSV,const HSVColor& overlay)
{
    float os = overlay.S;
    float ov = overlay.V;

    float Min;
    float Chroma;
    float Hdash;
    float X;
     RGBColor RGB{0,0,0};

    Chroma = os * ov; // Orginal was HSV.S * HSV.V
    Hdash = HSV.H / 60.0;
    X = Chroma * (1.0 - abs(fmod(Hdash , 2.0) - 1.0));

    if(Hdash < 1.0)
    {
        RGB.R = Chroma;
        RGB.G = X;
    }
    else if(Hdash < 2.0)
    {
        RGB.R = X;
        RGB.G = Chroma;
    }
    else if(Hdash < 3.0)
    {
        RGB.G = Chroma;
        RGB.B = X;
    }
    else if(Hdash < 4.0)
    {
        RGB.G= X;
        RGB.B = Chroma;
    }
    else if(Hdash < 5.0)
    {
        RGB.R = X;
        RGB.B = Chroma;
    }
    else if(Hdash <= 6.0)
    {
        RGB.R = Chroma;
        RGB.B = X;
    }

    Min = ov - Chroma; // Orginal was HSV.V - Chroma

    RGB.R += Min;
    RGB.G += Min;
    RGB.B += Min;

    return RGB;
}

int main(){
    RGBColor base{51, 34, 68};
    RGBColor overly{85, 119, 17};

    RGBColor r = Saturate(RGBToHSV(base),RGBToHSV(overly));

    cout << int(r.R*255) << endl;
    cout << int(r.G*255) << endl;
    cout << int(r.B*255) << endl;
}
```

original HSV <-> RGB converter code here: http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/HSV-RGB_Conversion

**question 2.**

With Saturation this is actually easy, After saturation blending use normal alpha blending in rgb color space.

```
RGBColor base;
RGBColor overly;    
RGBColor saturated = Saturate(base,overly);
RGBColor result = AlphaBlend(base,saturated,overly.alpha);
```

Note: this may not work with other blending modes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are equations for different Photoshop blending modes:

```
    inline float Blend_Normal( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Base;
    }
    inline float Blend_Lighten( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay > Base ) ? Overlay : Base;
    }
    inline float Blend_Darken( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay > Base ) ? Base : Overlay;
    }
    inline float Blend_Multiply( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Base * Overlay;
    }
    inline float Blend_Average( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Base + Overlay ) / 2.0f;
    }
    inline float Blend_Add( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return LMin( Base + Overlay, 1.0f );
    }
    inline float Blend_Subtract( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return LMax( Base + Overlay - 1.0f, 0.0f );
    }
    inline float Blend_Difference( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return fabs( Base - Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_Negation( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return 1.0f - fabs( 1.0f - Base - Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_Screen( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return 1.0f - ( 1.0f - Base ) * ( 1.0f - Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_Exclusion( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Base + Overlay - 2 * Base * Overlay;
    }
    inline float Blend_Overlay( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < 0.5f ) ? ( 2.0f * Base * Overlay ) : ( 2.0f * Base - 1.0f ) * ( 1.0f - Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_SoftLight( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < 0.5f ) ? ( Base + 0.5f ) * Overlay : ( Base - 0.5f ) * ( 1.0f - Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_HardLight( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Blend_Overlay( Overlay, Base );
    }
    inline float Blend_ColorDodge( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay > 1.0f - Math::EPSILON ) ? Overlay : LMin( 1.0f, Base / ( 1.0f - Overlay ) );
    }
    inline float Blend_ColorBurn( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < Math::EPSILON ) ? Overlay : LMax( 0.0f, 1.0f - ( 1.0f - Base ) / Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_LinearDodge( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Blend_Add( Base, Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_LinearBurn( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Blend_Subtract( Base, Overlay );
    }
    inline float Blend_LinearLight( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < 0.5f ) ? Blend_LinearBurn( Base, 2 * Overlay ) : Blend_LinearDodge( Base, ( 2 * ( Overlay - 0.5f ) ) );
    }
    inline float Blend_VividLight( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < 0.5f ) ? Blend_ColorBurn( Base, 2 * Overlay ) : Blend_ColorDodge( Base, ( 2 * ( Overlay - 0.5f ) ) );
    }
    inline float Blend_PinLight( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay < 0.5f ) ? Blend_Darken( Base, 2 * Overlay ) : Blend_Lighten( Base, ( 2 * ( Overlay - 0.5f ) ) );
    }
    inline float Blend_HardMix( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Blend_VividLight( Base, Overlay ) < 0.5f ) ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    }
    inline float Blend_Reflect( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return ( Overlay  > 1.0f - Math::EPSILON ) ? Overlay : LMin( 1.0f, Base * Base / ( 1.0f - Overlay ) );
    }
    inline float Blend_Glow( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return Blend_Reflect( Overlay, Base );
    }
    inline float Blend_Phoenix( float Base, float Overlay )
    {
        return LMin( Base, Overlay ) - LMax( Base, Overlay ) + 1.0f;
    }
```

From [Linderdaum Engine SDK](http://www.linderdaum.com).

Comment: No no no! I what the color/hue/saturation blending with alpha. you can to reproduce this in photoshop/gimp/pixelmator: create a base layer and fill it, create a new layer and fill it too. next step - change layer overlay from normal to color and change optically. color layer can be implemented using the HSV/HSL. but I can't understand how to implement optically.